# Is "driving" a road vehicle fullfiling SAE J3016 level 3 considered working time according to ArbZG?

Tags: germany, vehicle, labor-law, autonomous

Is being on the driver's seat of a [SAE J3016](https://www.sae.org/standards/content/j3016_202104/) level 3 road vehicle (i.e. a motor vehicle defined by a third-party standards agency as having "Conditional Driving Automation") considered working time according to [ArbZG](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/arbzg/) (i.e. the Arbeitszeitgesetz, which is the German "Working Hours Act"), while in autonomous mode?

Comment: I have gone ahead and defined the terms for you since you are a new user. But in general, abbreviations used in a question should be spelled out in the text of your question rather than relying on links which could go bad in the future (for the benefit of future users of Law.SE) and non-English language terms should be given a translation in English.

Comment: Probably just as much as sitting in a security booth at the entrance of a facility and looking at the monitor.

Comment: There is no such vehicle that is allowed to drive without a fully attentive driver monitoring every  action of the car at the moment.

Comment: @Trish The Daimler/ Mercedes S class with "drive pilot" has it at least in Germany, see: https://group.mercedes-benz.com/innovation/case/autonomous/drive-pilot-2.html .

Comment: @TorstenKnodt you can't drive on public roads without the driver in the seat and being able to interfere at any moment. The Car Park example is a) off the road b) in an area unavailable for pedestrians. Fully automated vehicles also work in container harbors, but they are in a fenced off area where pedestrians are not allowed and with a safety system that shuts down the harbor in case of foot traffic is detected.